# get variable name passing the value to a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to get the name of the parameter used to pass in the value to a stored procedure

In the below example i would like to be able to get the parameter name @Total within the proc dbo.usp_variableTest

This is a test procedure to provide an example of how there is a variable named @Var1 receiving a value

```
create procedure dbo.usp_variableTest (@var1 varchar)
as
.....



When i execute the below statement i am using a variable named @Total to pass a value to into @Var1

Declare @Total int
Select @Total=1
exec dbo.usp_variableTest @Var1=@Total
```

Can i get the name/datatype of the variable being passed into @Var1, in this case it would be @Total and the datatype would be an integer

The purpose of this is to integrate a very simple way to log the details of the variable being passed in for logging.

for example today i would have to write an insert statement for each variable like so

insert into tlog
select 'Variable:'+cast(@Total as varchar)
etc
etc

i would like to create a proc that can take many optional variables and auto log them for me, using the datatype to case and coalesce where needed

exec usp_LogVariables @Total, @id, @product, @brand

I can then log manay variables in just one line of code

Comment: Why does the name of the variable matter inside the SP? It'll be outside of scope inside of it. `SELECT @Total;` within the procedure will give the error *'Must declare the scalar variable "@Total"'* even *if* that was the name of the variable used for the value of `@Val1`. What is the *real* problem you're trying to solve here?

Comment: And if the value passed was a literal? When called from an application, how would the database engine know anything about the application code and how it attempted to execute the procedure? Looks like a big [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is unclear what is *really* being asked. The question being asked doesn't make any sense, as a variable used outside of the procedure isn't in scope within the procedure, and a variable might not even be used. This requires more information on what is really being asked as this is clearly an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: please review for reopening

Comment: The answer is no :)

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't make much sense to me either. 
Nevertheless, here's a possible solution that could accomplish what you seek.
Change the Proc declaration as:

```sql
create procedure dbo.usp_variableTest (@varValue varchar, @varName varchar, @varDataType int )
as
```